# Windows Service in C# works on dev machine, crashes in test environment

Tags: c#, service

I have been working on an application using .NET 4 and c# in Visual Studio 2010 Express. It's purpose is to watch a directory and import any documents it finds into our imaging system.

I included an installer class which provides the information needed by installutil.exe.

So to install locally, I build the solution, and then at command line:

```
installutil.exe MyProjectExecutable.exe
```

Which installs it as a service. This works fine in my development environment.

To deploy to the test environment, I use the same method:

```
installutil.exe MyProjectExecutable.exe.deploy
```

Except of course the executable has a second extension, .deploy. This is the way the application is published by Visual Studio. Everything works up tot his point

Here is the problem: once I have done this, I run the service and it starts properly, as indicated in the log file. However, once it detects files in the directory, the service will not do anything with them and will eventually crash. The only way I can tell it has crashed is to look in the windows Event Viewer. It will show the message:

"An unhandled win32 exception occurred in MyProjectExecutable.exe.deploy [4108]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: Debugger could not be started because no user is logged on."

Two questions:

1) What could be causing this

2) Am I going through the correct steps to install a windows service, or is there a better way?

Both environments have .NET 4 installed.
In both environments I am placing the same documents in the import directory.
In both environments the service runs under the Local System account.
If my question reflects a lack of C# experience, my apologies in advance.

Answer (score 0):

subscribe to [AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you watching a directory under 'Documents and Settings?'  You mention that you're running under Local System, but is that in the C# code or in the Services Panel?

- Start->Run
- services.msc
- < Find your App >
- Right-click, Properties
- Log On Tab
- Log On As
- - This Account
- - < Plug in a user / pass with permissions >

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this it is always a security problem.  Check the rights that the service running user has.  Can it access the folders you are monitoring and make the needed changes?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. in the config file, the listen directory was "c" whereas it should have been "C". Until now, I didn't think Windows was case-sensitive. Thanks for the help guys.